# $G$ noncyclic, $|G|=p^3$, $p$ an odd prime. Let $\varphi: x\mapsto x^p$. Show that if $|\text{ker}(\varphi)|=p^2$, then $E\cong Z_p\times Z_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

**The Problem**: $G$ noncyclic, $|G|=p^3$, $p$ an odd prime, . Let $E=\text{ker}(\varphi)$, where $\varphi: G\to Z(G)$ is $x\mapsto x^p$. Show that if $G$ contains an element of order $p^2$, then $E\cong Z_p\times Z_p$.

I am aware that there is a slight difference between my title and my problem; but note that "$|\text{ker}(\varphi)|=p^2$" implies "$G$ contains an element of order $p^2$".

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra, $\mathit{3^{rd}}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote.

In Section 5.5 (Semidirect Product), where the book discusses the classification of groups of order $p^3$, $p$ an odd prime, one paragraph goes:

> Let $x$ be an element of order $p^2$ and let $H=\left\langle
> x\right\rangle$. Note that since $H$ has index $p$, $H$ is normal is
> $G$ by Corollary 4.5. If $E$ is the kernel of the $p^{th}$ power map,
> **then in this case $\mathbf{E\cong Z_p\times Z_p}$ and $\mathbf{E\cap H=\left\langle x^p\right\rangle}$**.

**My Question**: I struggle to show the boldface texts in the quoted paragraph. I understand that either $E\cong Z_{p^2}$ or $E\cong Z_p\times Z_p$; but I failed to deduce a contradiction by assuming the former. And even if we derived the latter (i.e., $E\cong 
Z_p\times Z_p$), how do we know that $E\cap H=\left\langle x^p\right\rangle$? Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every element of $E$ must be of order dividing $p$, since every element is mapped to the identity by $\varphi$. It cannot be the cyclic group of order $p^2$.

Comment: Likewise, clearly the intesection of $E$ with $H$ contains the elements of order dividing $p$ of $H$, and nothing more. This is precisely the subgroup generated by $x^p$, since $H$ is cyclic of order $p^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel is made of $p^2-1$ elements of order $p$, plus the identity. So, $p^2-1=k(p-1)$, where $k$ is the number of subgroups of $E$ of order $p$, namely $k=p+1$. Take any two of them, say $K$ and $L$. Since $K\cap  L=\{e\}$, then $|KL|=p^2=|E|$; but $KL\subseteq E$, then $KL=E$. Moreover, $E$ is abelian (as its order is $p^2$). So, $E\cong K\times L\cong Z_p\times Z_p$.